# SourceTree git commit displays with no parent after deleting tag and rebasing

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

Pretty sure this is a SourceTree issue. Somehow the main log history has terminated at a tag (#988058d), and then continued on from a sibling commit with what appears to be no parent at all (#0803b25):

[image: SourceTree Log View]

That #0803b25 commit's parent is #988058d (the one that above it that terminates unexpectedly). Looking at both their commit times, they are exactly the same. So it's like it has ordered cronologically, mixed up the order of those 2, and is now displaying it very weirdly.

But stranger still, if I delete the 0.9.8 tag, it re-renders correctly:

[image: SourceTree Fixed]

What happened was I committed, tagged and released a build, but before pushing someone else updated master (with commit #db7151a). So my push of the tag succeeded, but my master push failed, which created a tagged commit diverging from master. So I rebased, deleted the tag (locally and from the remote), re-tagged the equivalent commit (which now also included 1 extra commit, the commit I rebased on top of), and then pushed.

I've tried every combination of deleting the tag (locally and remote), retagging, and pushing. Every time that tag comes back, the order screws up.

Ideas?

Comment: SourceTree has some issues with the ordering when commit times are the same with different branches/tags.
https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/SRCTREE-1818

Comment: That would be it, thanks! Feel free to change your comment to an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SourceTree has issues with the ordering when commit times are the same with different branches/tags.

This the existing JIRA issue: https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/SRCTREE-1818

Comment: Over a year later, the same thing keeps happening. It seems the SourceTree guys have not even verified the bug yet.